# What Caused Jerusalem to be Destroyed?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem, churban-destruction

The *Gemara* states the following:

1. Abaye said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because people desecrated the Shabbos in it ([*Shabbos* 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
2. Rabbi Abbahu said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because its citizens intentionally omitted recitation of Shema morning and evening ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
3. Rav Hamnuna said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because schoolchildren there were interrupted from studying Torah ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
4. Rabbi Yitzḥak said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because its small and the great citizens were equated. They did not properly value the prominent leaders of their generation ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))
5. Rav Amram, son of Rabbi Shimon bar Abba, said that Rabbi Shimon bar Abba said that Rabbi Ḥanina said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because the people did not rebuke one another ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.9?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))
6. Rabbi Yehuda said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because they disparaged the Torah scholars ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.9?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))
7. Rava said: Jerusalem was destroyed only because there were no more trustworthy people there ([ibid. 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.119b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
8. Jerusalem was destroyed on account of Kamtza and bar Kamtza ([*Gittin* 55b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.55b.17?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
9. Rabbi Yoḥanan says: Jerusalem was destroyed only for the fact that they adjudicated cases on the basis of Torah law in the city... they established their rulings on the basis of Torah law and did not go beyond the letter of the law ([*Bava Metzia* 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.30b.14?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Elsewhere, tractate [*Yuma* 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.9b.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [*Yerushalmi, Yuma* 4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yoma.4b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states the following:

Why was the Second Temple destroyed? It was destroyed due to the fact that there was שנאת חנם, *wanton hatred*, during that period...

Was Jerusalem's destruction triggered by the nine reasons that the *Gemara* lists above or did שנאת חנם, *wanton hatred*, seal the fate (i.e. cause Hashem) to destroy Jerusalem?

Comment: IMHO, the destruction/fall of Jerusalem is synonymous to the destruction of the 2nd Temple everywhere.

Comment: @AlBerko That would put a whole different spin on "אחרונים שלא נתגלה עונם לא נתגלה קצם" ([Yoma 9b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.9b.12?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)).

Comment: @AlBerko My thinking as well. However, perhaps, there was some thinking in the Gemara that separated events that happened before the 1st Temple vs. the 2nd. After all, all the *Nevi'im* seemd to indicate that there would be a rebuilding of the 2nd Temple, so there was a notion that Jerusalem wouldn't be destroyed.

Comment: You ask whether it's like _Yoma_ or like the combination of _Shabas_, _Gitin_, and _BM_, but could as well have asked a four-way contradiction among the four _masechtos_.